# Using matplotlib to plot dataframe that has gaps in date

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, series

I am currently generating a plot with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\Gm.xlsx', skiprows=0, sheet_name='MASCHDAT')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['DATUM','W020'])

df['DATUM'] = df['DATUM'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.set_index('DATUM',inplace=True)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 8)

df['W020'].plot(grid = True)

df.head()
df.tail()
print(df.head())
print(df.tail())e
```

So my the data go from 2019-05 to 2019-12, increments by 2 minutes.

[image: Graph]

How can I avoid plotting these trending  line between some dates in the entire data? I  want to see these gaps.
And as you also see in the picture. The plot makes a trending line, like there would be a gap, around September but there is some data there. Why is it making there, do i have to change to dotted lines?

Comment: A line plot will always connect the data points. Perhaps you should tray a scatter plot if you don't want the lines.

Comment: @ghosts does ur data contain missing values?

Comment: no there arent missing values

Comment: you can either add the missing dates and keep their values NaN and change the plot marker to "-" or, you can plot fractions of the data on a single plot

Comment: `plt.plot(data.index<certain period)` multiple times.

Comment: Group your data by whatever the criteria are that create your groups and plot the groups into one figure like it is done [here (but not into several subplots)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64928953/8881141).